# how to access parent class constructor into child class in codeigniter

Tags: php, inheritance

parent class

```
class Main {
          private $ci;
            public function __construct()
    {      
             $this ->ci=& get_instance();
             $this ->ci->load->database();
    }
}
```

child class

```
   class Commonlib extends main { 

    public function __construct()
    {      
              parent::__construct();
    }
       function getcountries(){
             $this->db->from($this->countries);
             $this->db->order_by("country", "ASC");
             $query = $this->db->get(); 
             return $query->result();

        }
}
```

i want to access  parent constructor variable in child class  as child class i use db variable 
how to access

```
i want to implement this code show this error

Fatal error: Class 'main' not found
```

Comment: there is typo in your child class use `Main` instead of `main`

Comment: i change as you say but  show this Fatal error: Class 'Main' not found  i'm in codeigniter using library classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per class inheritance you should be able to do something similar to `parent:: __construct`.

As for the error of class `class main not found` ensure the child class has the correct use statement at the beginning and the autoloader array map has class main mapped.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php